# WCF or WCF RESTful

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, wcf, ionic-framework

What service will be more suitable when using **angularjs** in a **ionic project** and a **WPF application**? What I want to do is I have an **application (C#)** and a **mobile (Angularjs)** app that both needs to connect to the service with methods returning data from a database. **WCF / WCF RESTful** ?

Thank you

Comment: wcf-restful.. but would be webapi

Comment: Would that be a problem with the WPF application? @entre

Comment: WebApi is designed for REST from the ground up, it was just tacked onto WCF. WebApi is also newer and in my experience much more productive and easier to use, no messing around with config, much better DI support, content, filters are much simpler than behaviors to name a few things.

Comment: If you already have a front end in WPF that is consuming WCF service. Then you would need to expose a RESTful WCF endpoint for consumption for angularjs.

Comment: Yeah that can work thanks @Chandermani